# iloc generates error while iterating through dataframes from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe, indexing

I have loaded my text files from a folder as Dataframes in to a dictionary with file name as the key. If I run a loop through my items in the dictionary to perform certain operations individually on my dataframes the iloc functions work for the first operation and then generates a single position index error.

```
 i = 0
 dict = {}
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
 for file in os.listdir(root):
    if file.endswith(".tlm-raw"):
        name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        dict[name] = pd.read_table(os.path.join(root,file),index_col=False,header=None, skiprows=53,engine='python')
```

Then I run a loop through my dictionary and let's say I want the 13th column from each of my dataframe. The first time I call my dataframe and slice using Iloc it works.

```
for k in dict:
    df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict[k])
    X=df.iloc[:,12]
    print(X)
```

Until then it works. But if I further wish to slice a column from it. Let's I want the 19th column. It raise the following error.

```
    y=df.iloc[:,18]
    **IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds**
```

My sincere request. What I actually want is load a files from a folder, store them as dataframes in a dictionary, then iterate through each of the dataframe, perform certain operations and store the modified dataframes in a new dictionary. What is the most feasible way of doing that?

Comment: It means there is no `20th` column, for `19.column` need `y=df.iloc[:,18]`

Comment: Edited my question. That is not an issue I have 120 columns to slice from.

Comment: Before the line causing the error, add `print(len(df.columns))`.  If you really had 120 columns, you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: @DSM should've done that. Found out one of my files just had one columns. And as I was looping through all these files/Dataframes the slicing index went out of bounds because of this erroneous file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need first change `dict` to `d`, because `dict` is python kyeword:

```
 i = 0
 d = {}
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
 for file in os.listdir(root):
    if file.endswith(".tlm-raw"):
        name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        d[name] = pd.read_table(os.path.join(root,file),index_col=False,header=None, skiprows=53,engine='python')
```

So `d` is `dictionary of DataFrame`s, so indexing is possible by:

```
d['file_name'].iloc[:, 9]
```

EDIT:

```
d1 = {}
for k, v in d.items()
  #modify v

  df1[k] = v
```

My edit:
Here I am supposing we have some dataframes in dictionary d, I am iterating through each of them by the key(which in my case is the Filename). Performing n operation on each them. Let's suppose we're trying to slice columns between 31st-94th column.

```
d1={}
for k in d:
  df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d[k])
  Result=pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:,30:93])
  d1[k]=pd.DataFrame(Result)
```

This way you have modified dictionary with same keys.

I think need:

```
d1={}
for k, v in d.items():
  d1[k] = v.iloc[:,30:93]
```

Or:

```
d1 = {k: v.iloc[:,30:93] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: It didn't make a difference. There was an erroneous file. But yes dict is a keyword should always choose something else.

Comment: @HannanMir - It is data problem like DSM pointed, so I try simplify your solution, because `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict[k])` is not necessary, need only `d['file_name']`. or `for k, v in d.items(): d[k]`

Comment: @HannanMir - But if my solution is not helpful I can delete my answer, no problem.

Comment: I had tried this way but had gotten error "TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

Comment: hmmm,  `for k, v in d.items(): print (v) print (type(v))` return `DataFrame` ?

Comment: Works. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I have one more question. Now thatI have iterated over all my data frames in the dictionary and  modified them. How to put them into a new dictionary.

Comment: Please check mine.